# Delete state from redux using createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer 'setOrder' that sets the initial state of 'order', however, I now want to create a reducer that deletes 'order' from the initial state. How would I go about doing this?

```
    const checkoutSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'checkout',
      initialState: {
        customer: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        },
        order: {
          wardrobeSize: ''
        }
      },
    
      reducers: {
        setCustomer(state, { payload }) {
          state.customer = payload;
        },
    
        setOrder(state, { payload }) {
          state.order = payload;
        }
      },
      extraReducers: hydrateServerToClient('checkout')
    });
    
    export const { setCustomer, setOrder } = checkoutSlice.actions;
    
    export default checkoutSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just assigning an empty object to it as:

```
emptyOrder(state) {
  state.order = {};
}
```